# I want to use ElasticSearch 6 or ElasticSearch 7 for searching

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

I am working on a product based project. I want to use Elasticsearch 7 or Elasticsearch 6 for product  searching. So I have some doubts:

1. Can I use it with Haystack? Can Haystack Support Elasticsearch 6 or 7?
2. Can I use Elasticsearch DSL?
3. or any other way to implement Elasticsearch6 or 7 with project?

Also please tell proper detail how to implement Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 1):

[The Haystack docs](https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/master/installing_search_engines.html) say that Elastic 1.x, 2.x, and 5.x are supported.

On GitHub there are [issues](https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/issues) about it not working with Elastic 7. In practice, you might find that it works with 6.x despite what the documentation says.

Answer (score 0):

1. Can I use with Haystack: Exactly not a Java developer. But, from haystack docs, I think you can. Ref - https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html
2. Can I used Elasticsearch DSL: Yes. You've to use Elasticsearch DSL queries to fetch any document info.
3. There are no other ways to fetch information from elasticsearch except Elasticsearch DSL queries.